# How to create new list from existing collection based on some criteria

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

Lets say, I have collection of custom objects in List. Each object has duration property set to some minutes (10 mins or 15 mins or 45 mins etc.,)

I have to group them in 3 hours of list. That is ListA will have collection of objects which Duration summation should be equal to 3 hours and so on. But final list need/need not be stick with 3 hours(that is might be lesser or equal)

Which algorithm should I use to read the object from list and create new lists based on 3 hours of total duration.

Difficulty here might be, Lets say I have 5 of 30mins object and 2 of 45 mins object. In ListA If I added 5 objects of 30 mins(6*50 = 150) as I read and I cannot add 1 object of 45 mins. Because that will not be equal to 3 hours. I would have added 2 of 45 mins objects first and 3 of 30 mins object next(2*45 + 3*30 = 3 hours) and let the other 2 object in another list.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I take it that the values in the list are in random order?

Comment: I'm not sure i got the idea exactly. But do you know about the knapsak problem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: @SpaceApple: You can take in random order.

Comment: Hossein Narimani's post looks like what his second list should include

Comment: Is there a fixed set of times?  If not is there a minimum and maximum?

Answer (score 1):

It can be easy if you try to store big objects first and completing with smaller.

Here is a quick code i made for you, and it works fine :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // data
        List<Int32> listElement = new List<Int32>() { 10, 20, 10, 30, 45, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 40, 30, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 20, 30, 10, 50, 60, 40, 60, 80, 90, 60, 80, 70, 80, 90, 90, 50 };
        Int32 MaxStack = 180;

        // result
        List<List<Int32>> listResult = new List<List<Int32>>();

        // process
        foreach (Int32 element in listElement.OrderByDescending(i => i))
        {
            List<Int32> listToStore = listResult.Where(l => l.Sum() + element <= MaxStack).FirstOrDefault();
            if (listToStore == null)
            {
                listToStore = new List<Int32>();
                listResult.Add(listToStore);
            }

            listToStore.Add(element);
        }

        // view
        foreach (List<Int32> list in listResult)
        {
            Console.Write("List " + (listResult.IndexOf(list) + 1) + "[total " + list.Sum() + "]: ");                
            foreach (Int32 element in list)
            {
                Console.Write(element.ToString() + " ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

For the example, it is in console, with Int32 object, but it is the same for complex objects.

All the thing is to read your list of objects from the bigger to the smaller, and find the first store list wich can store it.

Result is :

```
List 1[total 180]: 90 90
List 2[total 180]: 90 90
List 3[total 180]: 80 80 20
List 4[total 180]: 80 80 20
List 5[total 180]: 70 70 40
List 6[total 180]: 60 60 60
List 7[total 180]: 60 60 50 10
List 8[total 180]: 50 50 50 30
List 9[total 175]: 45 40 40 30 20
List 10[total 90]: 30 30 10 10 10
```

**Edit :** If you want as much as list at 180, this is a (quicky and missy) code you can add between process and view :

```
        // switching element for better fill
        List<List<Int32>> unfilledlist = listResult.Where(l => l.Sum() < MaxStack).ToList();
        // truncate original result
        unfilledlist.ForEach(l => listResult.Remove(l));

        while (unfilledlist != null && unfilledlist.Count > 1)
        {
            List<Int32> list = unfilledlist.First();
            unfilledlist.Remove(list);

            foreach (Int32 element in list)
            {
                Int32 needed = MaxStack - list.Sum() + element;
                Boolean isFound = false;

                foreach (List<Int32> smallerlist in unfilledlist)
                {
                    List<Int32> switchingList = new List<int>();

                    // searching how to fill what we needed
                    foreach (Int32 e in smallerlist.OrderByDescending(i => i))
                    {
                        if (e + switchingList.Sum() <= needed)
                            switchingList.Add(e);
                    }

                    // we found a possible switch
                    if (switchingList.Sum() == needed)
                    {
                        // moving first element
                        list.Remove(element);
                        smallerlist.Add(element);

                        // moving element
                        switchingList.ForEach(e => { smallerlist.Remove(e); list.Add(e); });
                        isFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (isFound)
                    break;
            }

            listResult.Add(list.OrderByDescending(i => i).ToList());
        }

        // completing result with lists that are not with sum 180
        unfilledlist.ForEach(l => listResult.Add(l.OrderByDescending(i => i).ToList()));
```

I'm not satisfied with this code, but it seems to work

New result :

```
List 1[total 180]: 90 90
List 2[total 180]: 90 90
List 3[total 180]: 80 80 20
List 4[total 180]: 80 80 20
List 5[total 180]: 70 70 40
List 6[total 180]: 60 60 60
List 7[total 180]: 60 60 50 10
List 8[total 180]: 50 50 50 30
List 9[total 180]: 40 40 30 30 20 10 10
List 10[total 85]: 45 30 10
```

Comment: @ Xaruth: 9th list has 175 which is smaller than 180. This one will not work. Can we fix that?

Comment: You can analyse lists, and switch items between lists wich are not at 180 (list with 180 of total are filled by the better way, with bigger items). For exemple, switching 45 of list 9 and 30+10+10 of list 10. But is that a good approch ? You can't be sure it is always possible to fill all lists at exact 180 (ex : objects {100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 50, 50}). In the opposite, if you have lot of small items, you will not have unfilled lists.

Comment: I added in edit a code for switching elements in order to fill list at better way.